# Is there vim support for git with ability to connect to repositories and perform git operations?

Tags: git, vim, push, pull

VS Code has integrated Git functionality and there are many extensions for other Git-related tasks. I've been searching for ways to do the same with Vim, but not found any. Are there vim extensions that integrate with Git for status information, and diff, and push/pull etc, for Git in general and GitHub in particular?

Comment: https://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=git&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, old [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). There also is [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter). Also [additional support](https://github.com/xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin) in [NERDTree](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree).
Just browse plugins on [Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/?q=tag:git) to find many

Not to mention that Vim has some build-in support and is commonly used as `mergetool`

Comment: @YorSubs Fugitive is first result of googling `vim git plugin`, so "_I've been searching_" is quite... you know. It's very common topic on various forums

Comment: 1. "vim", "git", and "extension" are all keywords extracted from your question which, put together in your favourite search engine, would have given you all the links above and then some in the first couple of pages. So no, you obviously didn't do _any_ research before posting your question. 2. "Questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" are forbidden on this site anyway. Try harder next time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Vim's built-in support for various Version Control Systems is pretty much limited to:

- syntax and formatting when you are doing things like `$ git commit`,
- the ability to execute arbitrary external commands with `:help :!`, like `:!git checkout feature/foo-bar`.

Beyond that, you will have to look for third-party plugins at [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?order_by=creation_date&direction=descending).